# Add additional images to articles in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I would like to have multiple images within one article in Joomla and decide in the template where to display them on the page.

Is there a way of increasing the number of images you can have from the default Intro Image and Full Article Image fields?

Ideally I would like to create new article custom fields, set the type as Image and then those new image custom fields are in the article creation screen.  Is this possible with Joomla?  I'm unfortunately new to the Joomla platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin to override the form to add the fields, since the data are  saved in json  this will work without having to set up a place to store.  Then do a layout overrider to do the posiioning.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I can't figure out how to achieve this, I can't find image_intro and image_fulltext anywhere in the plugins, only in the administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml . How can I override this? Can you provide some pointers? Thank you in advance

Comment: Image intro and full ane part of the core so they don't need plugins. But you use a plugin to override forms.  What you want to do is to add additional fields to the form edit layout and you use a plugin to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you add multiple image without article you have one way for that type add image you know components in joomla you have required  first create custom components than you add in menu than u add multiple image than you check the position where you add image `?tp=1`  you add url in last